# Is it possible to apply grayscale to a View?

Tags: android, view, grayscale

I know it's possible to apply a grayscale filter to a bitmap, I was wondering if it's possible to apply it to a view. the point of doing this is to grey out a `GridView` element within the adapter's `getView()`

Comment: Anything happening in the view while it's grayed out? If not, is there a way you can create a bitmap from the contents of your view, then add your grayscale filter and lay the bitmap over the GridView itself to give the appearance of a grayed out view?

Answer (score 0):

you can apply it to bitmap and set it as gridview's background

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adaptercategories, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();              
                holder.txtCategoryName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoryName);
                vi.setTag(holder);

                            // set the bitmap here for vi's background 

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }

        return vi;
    }
```

Comment: The point is to make the entire view grey not just the background

Comment: So set view background in getview()

Comment: and what about all the other components within convertView? I was trying to find a way to apply a grey scale to filter to convertView

Answer (score 0):

Try creating an ImageView with transparency and positioning it to cover the activity.

You can set its visibility to gone and then just display and position it when you need it.